# Set "acts-as-taggable-on" Taggings association to touch Taggable on save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tags, acts-as-taggable-on

I am currently using the acts-as-taggable-on gem to add tags to my Pieces model.

I am using elasticsearch to add an index of the tags to Pieces.

However to update the index when a tagging is created I need to make the associations

```
belongs_to :taggable, touch: true
```

In the Tagging model.

[Here](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/master/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/tagging.rb) is a link to the Tagging model in acts-as-taggable-on

How can I add the touch: true association to the Taggings model so that my Piece index is updated when I create a Tagging for that piece?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I figured it out.

There are two steps to this. First you must set up the belongs_to association in the Tagging model to include the "touch: true" option. This can be done in the acts_as_taggable.rb initializer like so:

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging.belongs_to :taggable, polymorphic: true, touch: true
```

Next we need to tell elasticsearch to reindex the Piece index every time a Piece is touched. This can be done by adding the following callback to the Piece model:

```
after_touch() { __elasticsearch__.index_document }
```